# Using printf for more than one type of a modifier

Tags: java

I want to print a number which has only 2 digits after the decimal symbol and also print a statement with a fixated spot for the number. The way i try to do this is by typing:

```
System.out.printf("You can take a trip. %s money left.",money);
```

but i have no idea where to put the other modifier which is "%.2f".
I tried:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f","You can take a trip. %s money left.",money);
```

but it doesn't work. Will appreciate the help.

Comment: `("I have $%.2f, you have $%.2f", myMoney, yourMoney)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass two different floating point values to `System.out.printf()`, then you can pass both of these values as the arguments of that method (but use `%f` instead of `%s`, as `%s` is used for strings and not for floating points:

```
float firstMoney = 1000.0f;
float secondMoney = 5.0f;
System.out.printf("%.2f. You can take a trip. %.2f money left.", firstMoney, secondMoney);
```

Output that you get:

```
1000,00. You can take a trip. 5,00 money left.
```

If the source of both of these values is the same variable, you can change code a bit, to let `System.out.printf()` know, that you want to pass the same argument to both format specifiers (you need to use `1$` to admit that for both you want to use first argument from the list (if you don't do that, method, by default looks for the second argument in the list, which is absent. For example:

```
float firstMoney = 1000.0f;
System.out.printf("%1$.2f. You can take a trip. %1$.2f money left.", firstMoney, secondMoney);
```

Outputs:

```
1000,00. You can take a trip. 1000,00 money left.
```

You can also replace the order of values passed to that method:

```
float firstMoney = 1000.0f;
float secondMoney = 5.0f;
System.out.printf("%2$.2f. You can take a trip. %1$.2f money left.", firstMoney, secondMoney);
```

Output:

```
5,00. You can take a trip. 1000,00 money left.
```

For additional informations, how to use format specifiers, you might want to have a look here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

Answer (score 1):

This formatted output palces your money value within a field of 15 spaces with two decimal places, so there will be a fixated spot for the number:

```
System.out.printf("You can take a trip. %15.2f money left.", money);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("You can take a trip. %.2f money left.", money);
```

The `%s` format specifier formats the corresponding value as a string; since you're trying to print out a floating point value, you need to use `%f`. The `.2` element specifies the number of digits after the decimal point that should be printed.

Sources:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html